# MySQL: What's faster? Getting many rows with a small amount of data each, or fewer rows with much more data in each?

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a PHP app. I store all my settings for this app in a MySQL table. Every row of this table is called on each page load.

Im wondering if this is the most efficient approach to take. Or would in be better to consolidate the data in those rows into a single row/column, that contains JSON of all the options instead?

Example - Current:

```
setting_1 | data1
setting_2 | data2
setting_3 | data3
```

Example - New approach:

```
settings | { "1" : "data1", "2" : "data2", "3" : "data3" }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why is every row called on each page load? Shouldn't you just call it once and then set in a session?

Comment: you can set settings in a global variable and access it anywhere.

Comment: If you use the SQL only for reading the whole row, then I think there should not be much difference between those two approaches.

Comment: Do you change these values often? If so, do they all change at once or do they change independently? Updating a single row is easier. You need to think about optimizing for read or write performance as you can't always have both. If these are settings then you can retrieve them as needed, not necessarily all at once.

Comment: If we are talking global settings then putting them in a config file (e.g. in json format) may be the better approach then making a DB query each time

Comment: Just curious, and not directly related to the answer of this, but if you store all your settings in the database, where do you store your database connection settings?

Comment: If these are global settings, not per user, then why not load them in once per application start? In that case the query overhead is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks all! to answer @Don'tPanic - these are hard coded in the app.

Comment: These settings do not change all that often - and I will be looking at some kind of caching behaviour - just haven't gotten to that point yet.

As an example, I have 12 rows all with credentials and configuration options for my payment processor. What im thinking is to create a single row, and a table cell will just contain ALL those details in one.

Im generally looking to group similar things all together - so things that are generally all used & needed at the same time, can be retrieved in one go.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between reading a set of rows versus one row containing equivalent data is insignificant. It's pretty much the same number of bytes.

If you're concerned about performance of fetching your settings, then don't read them from the database on every page load. Read them from a cache in memory instead.

Most performance-conscious web apps use an instance of Redis or Memcached to complement their database.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably fetching all data with a single statement is faster since the overhead of connection handling, marshalling, protocol handling and so on outweights everything else. This story may change if you are about to transfer gigabytes of data, but this is uncommon for a configuration file.